# chrome logger - how to get console output

Tags: php, chromelogger

I installed chrome extension - chrome logger.

download and include `ChromePhp.php` in my php page.

write:

```
ChromePhp::log('Hello console!');
console.log('Hello console!');
```

nothing happpend - console is empty.

what is wrong or missing ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromePhp::log('Hello console!');
ChromePhp::warn('warn console!');
```

after Inspect.(Developer Tools->**Console**)in Tap **Default levels** choose Default.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the extension is enabled for the site.

You need to click the extension's icon in the top-right of Chrome. It looks like a console/terminal. If it's blue it's enabled.

[image]

If it looks black like this, then you won't see any output in the console.

[image]